# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class x.y.z due to missing dependency javax/xml/bind/ValidationEventLocator after upgrade to jdk11

Tags: spring-boot, maven, groovy, java-11, gmaven

We have a spring boot project. Once the JDK is upgraded from 8 to 11 , there are groovy test-scripts which are failing with below exception

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class x.y.z.Class due to missing dependency javax/xml/bind/ValidationEventLocator
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.convertUncaughtExceptionToCompilationError(CompilationUnit.java:1083)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1061)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:583)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:561)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:538)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:517)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
a

It is using gmaven plugin to compile the groovies in test script.

'''

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version></version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <providerSelection>2.0</providerSelection>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven.runtime</groupId>
                        <artifactId>gmaven-runtime-2.0</artifactId>
                        <version>1.4</version>
                        <exclusions>
                            <exclusion>
                                <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                                <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                            </exclusion>
                        </exclusions>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3.8</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>`
```

'''
I already have jaxb dependency added in pom.xml

'''

```
<dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2.7</version>
                </dependency>
```

'''

Comment: Pass the command line argument, `--add-modules java.xml.bind`, to your test runner.

Comment: Thanks @lane.maxwell . I am just building the project using mvn clean isntall . How can i include this in comand line argument and also while deploying on the server.

Comment: https://groovy-lang.org/releasenotes/groovy-2.5.html#Groovy2.5releasenotes-Addendum251